# Is it haram to move out before getting married?

Tags: halal-haram, parents

My parents say it’s haram to move out before marriage. I’m gay though and I don’t want to disappoint god and my family for acting upon it and marrying a man. Would this mean I would have to marry a woman to move out?

Answer (score 0):

There's no hadith speaking about restrictions to a man leaving home. It would be unfair to marry a woman if you are not in the condition to marry a woman.